# ¿Como puedo recibir un archivo en el backend y mas otros datos de un formulario?

Tags: ajax, nodejs, archivo, upload

les quedaria muy agradecido si podrian darme una ayuda, me tranque aqui, les comento un poco de mi problema, deseo hacer el cargado (con `SKIPPER` con `Nodejs`) de un archivo mas otros datos mas como ser, `nombre`, `Tipo de Archivo`, `Descripción`, `Tamaño` y el propio archivo, deseo enviar todo el formulario mas el archivo por metodo `ajax` y no lo estoy consiguiendo. No se si lo estoy haciendo mal en el frontend o el backend, por favor si pudieran ayudarme, le quedaria muy agradecido.

[image: Este es el formulario que deseo mandar]

**esto es el JS que hace la lógica del envió al BACKEND mediante una API**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '#btn-save-archivo', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
    var data = new FormData(form);

    $("#btn-save-archivo").prop("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      url: '{{ route('
      archivo.save ') }}',
      data: {
        id: $("#id").val(),
        idPalabra: $("#idPal").val(),
        nombre: $("#nombre").val(),
        tipoArchivo: $("#archivo_seleccionada").val(),
        descripcion: $("#descripcion").val(),
        size: $("#tamaño").val(),

      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      timeout: 600000,
      success: function(data) {

        $("#result").text(data);
        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
        $("#btn-save-archivo").prop("disabled", false);

      },
      error: function(e) {

        $("#result").text(e.responseText);
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        $("#btn-save-archivo").prop("disabled", false);

      }
    });

  });

});
```

**Este el codigo del Backend que recibe del Frontend**

```js
router.post('/archivo', (req, res, next) => {

  console.log("Cuerpo: ", req.body)
  req.file('avatar').upload({
      maxBytes: 1000000000,
      dirname: require('path').resolve(__dirname, '../../public'),
      saveAs: function(nombreArchivo, cb) {
        var extension = nombreArchivo.filename.split('.')[1]
        cb(null, req.body.nombre + "." + extension);
      }
    },
    function(err, uploadedFiles) {
      if (err) return res.send(500, err);
      return res.json({
        message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
        files: uploadedFiles
      });
    });

  return servicios.Archivo.crear(req.body)
    .then((archivos) => {
      return res.status(201).json(archivos);
    })
    .catch(next);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en el request `Ajax` no estás enviando el archivo que quieres subir.
para eso puedes enviarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-save-archivo', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var inputFormData = new FormData();
    //llenas tu form con el archivo y lo demás
    var inputFileImage = document.getElementById(“nombreDeTuInput”);

    var file = inputFileImage.files[0];

    inputFormData.append('avatar',file);
    inputFormData.append('id', $("#id").val());
    inputFormData.append('idPalabra', $("#idPal").val());
    //... los demas valores

    $("#btn-save-archivo").prop("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      url: '{{ route('
      archivo.save ') }}',
      data: inputFormData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      timeout: 600000,
      success: function(data) {

        $("#result").text(data);
        console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
        $("#btn-save-archivo").prop("disabled", false);

      },
      error: function(e) {

        $("#result").text(e.responseText);
        console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        $("#btn-save-archivo").prop("disabled", false);

      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: ¿en esta linea de codigo se refiere al nombre del input-file que carga el archivo?

var inputFileImage = document.getElementById(“nombreDeTuInput”);

Comment: @MarceloEscalera corresponde al `id` de un inputfile